# Convert WPF to PDF

Tags: wpf, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a WPF application and I want to be able to save the output of the application to a PDF document, the item I want to save can be a Visual a Drawing or a FixedDocument (I can create it as any of those options, and it's easy to convert between them).

Is there any library that can convert directly from WPF to PDF (without writing code to walk the visual tree and recreate it using PDF primitives).

Answer (score 6):

If you got your WPF visual tree rendered in to XPS  then try this XPS to PDF converter [NIXPS](http://nixps.blogspot.com/2008/04/convert-xps-to-pdf.html).

Answer (score 4):

For this sceneario I recommend using [XpsDocumentWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.xps.xpsdocumentwriter.aspx) class to get a XPS document, then converting it to PDF using [Amyuni PDF Creator](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreator)
*Disclaimer: I work for Amyuni Technologies*

Comment: Do you offer any sort of free support for people evaluating your product? The forums are close to dead and there are several questions about your product that have gone unanswered.

Comment: @Mick Yes, there is free support during evaluation.

Answer (score 3):

We have just released a new library that facilitates this: [NiPDF v1.0](http://nixps.com/nipdf/index.html)

[Here is a link](http://nixps.com/nipdf/example0001.html) to an example on our site that converts WPF to PDF.

It is a 100% managed .NET assembly, and you don't need to learn an arcane API top be able to use it.