# Save to PDF in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

i have a report and i print it using PrintVisual ,now i need to save it in PDF file but i don't know how export it in PDF.
Do you know how i can do it?
Thanks for your attention.

Nice Regards
:)

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123947/wpf-to-pdf

Answer (score 3):

I hear good stuff about [PDFsharp](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/).

Comment: Thanks JP,
it is a good stuff but id not allow me to save my visuals(canvas,stackPanel) in Pdf ,i will try better if i can work out this feature.

Comment: It can, look here: http://www.nathanpjones.com/wp/2013/03/output-to-pdf-in-wpf-for-free/

Answer (score 3):

You can also try [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/).

The tutorial for iTextSharp is available [here](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/).