# Print a System.Windows.Controls.Page as a PDF Document

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf

How can I print WPF Pages (`System.Windows.Controls.Page` Type) as PDF Documents?

So far, I am able to print part of a page with the following code:

```
//Create A New Event Handler (ButtonBase.Click Type)
private void Print_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Create A New Print Dialog
        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        //Print The Page
        printDialog.PrintVisual(GlobalVariables.conceptForm, "New PDF Document");
    }
```

Note, `GlobalVariables.conceptForm` is a WPF Page instantiated in a Global Variable Class, my WPF Pages have scroll viewers (`System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer` Type) and the printout I'm getting right now is a single page containing only the part of the page that was on the screen when I clicked on the "Print" button.

Thank you in advance!

Edit:

Thank you for replying and redirecting me to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232676/print-wpf-window-to-pdf-file), [IDisposable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5621607/idisposable). Unfortunately I have already tried it with the following code of mine:

```
private void print_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
    //Set up the WPF Control to be printed
        Page controlToPrint = GlobalVariables.conceptForm;
        controlToPrint.DataContext = GlobalVariables.conceptForm;

        FixedDocument fixedDoc = new FixedDocument();
        PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
        FixedPage fixedPage = new FixedPage();

    //Create first page of document
        fixedPage.Children.Add(controlToPrint);
        ((System.Windows.Markup.IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(fixedPage);
        fixedDoc.Pages.Add(pageContent);
    //Create any other required pages here

    //View the document
        documentViewer.Document = fixedDoc;
}
```

I have also tried similar renditions of the solution above, but every time I click on "Print" my Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 crashes and breaks the program. It then shows me this line of the code: `fixedPage.Children.Add(controlToPrint);` and tells me that `An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll`. When I click on "View Details", it shows me the `Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException {"Page can have only Window or Frame as parent."}`

I do not know if I am doing this right or something terribly wrong or just not seeing something obviously wrong, either way I am getting a bit frustrated with this and have been trying to solve this for a week now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, please.

Again, thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [print wpf window to pdf file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232676/print-wpf-window-to-pdf-file)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, I posted an edit above, please take a look at it @IDisposable

Comment: Sorry. I am in a hurry. I think, it's because you have to pass a Window which contains the `GlobalVariables.conceptForm` for printing. Anyways I will check and try to provide a complete solution asap.