# WPF conver to PDF

Tags: wpf, pdf, xps

I´m progammming a application in WPF and I need to export to PDF.

I have a Listbox and in this Lisbtox I have differents items with a Canvas and differentes Images.

```
<Grid x:Name="gridView">
    <ListBox x:Name="listBoxView" Width="850"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource templateListBoxView}" 
                        ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemView}"
                        ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ItemsPanelTemplateListView}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ViewObject}" >
     </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

I´ve been reading about this and the best way is to convert it in XPS and after to convert XPS in PDF.

Is it the best way?

Can somebody explain How to export a listbox in XPS?

EDIT

I´ve found a solution.

It´s in this webpage: http://www.ericsink.com/wpf3d/B_Printing.html

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: see this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123947/wpf-to-pdf  or use free dll such as DOCX